# Get the correct process ID in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

While examining Linux Kernel, to get the process ID they use:

```
pid_t pid = current->pid;
```

But in some places I saw:

```
pid_t pid = task_tgid_vnr(current);
```

I wonder the rationale behind it and where should I use the one instead of the other?

(Detailed explanations will also be welcomed)

Comment: `pid` is proccess pid, `tgid` is thread thread group id. These are different things. What you want `tgid` access `current->tgid`, when you want `pid` use `current->pid`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, why dont we use `current->tgid` instead of `task_tgid_vnr` ?

Comment: @FredrickGauss search for duplicates before asking a question next time. :)

Comment: @gsamaras, I already searched but could not find a decent explanation about `task_tgid_vnr`.

Comment: `task_tgid_vnr` fetches the `tgid` from a the pid namespace, while `current->tgid` is from init namespace. You check man pid_namespace and [kernel soruce](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1233).